# Typescript class creation invoking many times

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am very new to Typescript, I have my AppComponent class, in the constructor am creating a new object for ServiceProvider. In the servcieProvider constructor again am creating a new object for ServcieProvider. As per my understanding there are two times ServiceProvider constructor should invoke but in my case continuously  object creating for ServiceProvider and finally am getting an ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Why it happened like this.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){
   var Service =new ServiceProvider();
  }
}  


export class ServiceProvider{
   name:String;

   constructor(){
        console.log("Invoking-service-provider-constructor");
        var t = new ServiceProvider();
        t.name="Test";
    }
   }
```

Comment: You creating a new instance of `ServiceProvider` inside the constructor of `ServiceProvider`. `new ServiceProvider()` invokes the `constructor`, so you are still inside the creation of `ServiceProvider` when you start creating a new `ServiceProvider` leading thus to a stack overflow exception

Comment: Why are you initializing a `new ServiceProvider()` in the `ServiceProvider` class? What initialization does is that, it calls the constructor of a class. So in this case, Angular tries to call the constructor of `ServiceProvider` and when it does that, your code tells it to call the constructor again which ends in a loop that's why you get that error message. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks Titian and ALF. Now only I started to learn Typescript so I just tried to create an object in different approach that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating instance of ServiceProvider in ServiceProvider constructor, when you create instance of a class it invokes constructor of that class, so it is calling recursively contructor of ServiceProvider.. at some point of time it creates so many instances of that class which fills up whole stack size. so error is coming as RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.